# stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The method is

```
private List<HighWay> getWillSave(List<HighWay> total,
        HighWayRepository repository) {

    List<HighWay> willSave = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
    int lastSaved = total.size() - 1;
    while (lastSaved >= 0
            && repository.exists(total.get(lastSaved).getId())) {
        lastSaved--;
    }
    willSave.addAll(total.subList(0, ++lastSaved));
    return willSave;
}
```

and now I try to change to stream like this, and I don't know the change whether is right:

```
private List<HighWay> getWillSave(Stream<HighWay> notDealItem,
        HighWayRepository repository) {

    List<HighWay> willSave = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
    long lastSaved = notDealItem.count()-1;
    while (lastSaved >= 0
            && repository.exists(notDealItem.skip(lastSaved-1).findFirst().get().getId())) {
        lastSaved--;
    }
    willSave.addAll(notDealItem.collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(0, (int)(++lastSaved)));
    return willSave;
}
```

but the exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon
>   or closed

I know the stream can be only consumed once. And the count and get method are all consumer way. But I really want to know the count and invoke the get method.

How to avoid the exception and solve the problem?

Should I refactor the code somehow?

Comment: You cannot expect to write similar code in an imperative style than in a functional style, you must think functional when using streams. Basically, you are trying to find the highest index for which the associated value is in the repository, right ?

Comment: i want find the list contained 0-index which is the first index not in database from the last index,for example, the list is {1,2,3,4,5,6},and when 5,6 is in database,so i want to find 1,2,3,4 list,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you can do something like that... but it is very unelegant compared as what we could do with a **real** functional language :

```
private List<HighWay> getWillSave(List<HighWay> total, HighWayRepository repository) {
    List<HighWay> willSave = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
    int size = total.size();
    int index = 
        IntStream.range(0,size)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(i,size - i - 1))
            .filter(p -> !repository.exists(p.getValue().getId()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> new Pair<>(0,null)).getKey();
    return total.subList(0,index);
}
```

Comment: intStream has range method?

Comment: Do you have Google ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic of your code, you want to return all items in the list/stream until you are at the point at which the remainder fail the test `repository.exists`. Is that correct? If so then it can be achieved with a custom collector:

```
class MyCollector {
    private List<Highway> acceptedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Highway> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void accept(Highway highway) {
        if (repostitory.exists(highway.getId())) {
            acceptedList.addAll(currentList);
            acceptedList.add(highway);
            currentList.clear();
        } else {
            currentList.add(highway);
        }
    }
    public Stream<Highway> stream() {
        return acceptedList.stream();
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear how that works: if items fail your test they are put into a temporary list until an item that passes is found. For the final series of failing items they are never put back into the final list. I've skipped the combiner for simplicity.

This can then be applied to your stream of highways as follows:

```
highwayStream()
    .collect(MyCollector::new, MyCollector::accept, null)
    .stream()
```

You can then do whatever you want including `.collect(Collectors.toList())` if you really need to return a `List` rather than another stream.

Having provided this solution let me say that I'm not convinced streams should be used for every purpose. They are best suited to situations in which the items are acted upon fairly independently. In your case the final list is very dependent on other items.

A more straightforward solution might be:

```
List<Highway> filteredList = new ArrayList(originalList);
int i = filteredList.size() - 1;
while (i >= 0 && repository.exists(filteredList.get(i).getId()))
    filteredList.remove(i--);
return filteredList;
```